# django template count for related models

Tags: django

I'm working on a rental project using django. I have an Inventory model and an owner's model. I'm trying to count in my template how many of the saved items in the Inventory belongs to a particular owner. Any help? Thanks. The owner model is related to the Inventory with a ForeignKey.

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Please do read this for help: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you need to use related name https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/.  owner_object.related_name.all().count()

Comment: in your template{{ inevtoryObject.owner_set.all.count }} this will give you total count of owner is related to inventory model